# What is period finding useful for in Shor's algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, shors-algorithm

Could someone help me to understand the concept behind period finding in Shor algorithm?. I'm a beginner in quantum computing.

I want to know why we use Shor's algorithm to find the period and what is the use of it.

Comment: https://youtu.be/lvTqbM5Dq4Q and https://youtu.be/FRZQ-efABeQ might be of interest

Answer (score 4):

It is helpful to first understand how to implement Shor's algorithm classically. Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRZQ-efABeQ), let's take

$$ N = 314191$$

---

**Step 1**: Make a random guess

$$G = 127$$

---

**Step 2**: Compute the greatest common divisor using Euclid's algorithm

$$ gcd(127,314191) = 1$$

If the $gcd > 1$, then we will have factorized N by pure luck.

---

**Step 3**: Find a number X such that

$$ 127^X = 1 \mod{314191}$$

By classical search,

$$X = 17388$$

---

**Step 4**: This implies that

$$127^{17388} = 314191m + 1$$
$$127^{17388} - 1 = 314191m$$
$$(127^{\frac{17388}{2}} - 1)(127^{\frac{17388}{2}} + 1) = 314191m$$
$$(127^{8694} - 1)(127^{8694} + 1) = 314191m$$

---

**Step 5**: It can be shown that X being an even number, one or both of the LHS factors $(127^{8694} - 1)(127^{8694} + 1)$ likely share some common factors with $314191$ (instead of $m$), ie.

$$gcd(127^{8694} \pm 1, 314319) > 1$$

occurs with a rather high probability of nearly $ 40 \% $.

Indeed,

$$gcd(127^{8694} + 1, 314319) = 829$$

and

$$gcd(127^{8694} - 1, 314319) = 379$$

are the two factors of $N = 314319$.

---

Period finding is specific to the quantum implementation of Shor's algorithm, where X occurs as periodic bumps of interval X. The purpose of period finding is to find X faster than is classically possible.

Answer (score 0):

Shor's algorithm is designed to work faster on a quantum computer since quantum computers run multiple steps simultaneously due to their ability to store qubits in superposition. We use period-finding in specific so we can apply QPE (quantum phase estimation). If you have not watched the [Veritasium video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UrdExQW0cs) on it, I would recommend watching that to understand the algorithm and understand a bit of why it works faster. In general, quantum algorithms are designed in a completely different way than classical algorithms. Hope that helps!